# Is there anything wrong with \char?

Tags: xetex, symbols

I usually have trouble remembering how to escape special latex characters: `\textbackslash`, `\textasciitilde`, `\textasciicircum`, `\textless`, `\textgreater`, `\$`, `\{`, etc.

Recently I found about `\char`; with it, I can write the following:

```
{\char`\\}
{\char`\~}
{\char`\^}
{\char`\<}
```

I like the consistency of this approach. Is there anything wrong with it? Are there caveats I should be aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\char` is not expandable (try

```
\typeout{\char`\<}
```

)

If you use

```
`\<
```

form to specify the argument you assume that the font encoding matches ascii for those characters which is not the case for the default OT1 encoding (

```
\char\`<
```

will produce the same output as `<` which is Spanish punctuation in the default encoding.

The brace group around the character

```
{\char``\<}
```

would break any ligatures or kerns with the character (which is possibly less of an issue with non alphabetic characters, but something to be aware of.

`\char` is a tex primitive with a typically odd argument syntax. the standard latex syntax for the functionality is `\symbol` which takes a standard `{}` delimited macro argument.

Comment: I see, thanks! But symbol is not expandable either, right (it just expands to \char)?

Comment: @Clément yes symbol just wraps char